# How I make a page view like a book with JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-recyclerview

[please see this image to get my point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F06pO.png)

I want to get text from **JSON** and add these texts like series circuit in my layout, but I can't understand how I make this possible.

You see the book lines. One line then second line then third, long lines are wrapped. I want exactly the same thing in my app.

Hope you understand what I wrote.

Comment: have you considered GridView? I see you only tried RecyclerView and ListView.

Comment: @Neone GridView also not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found!! https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout this library made my day

Use **Flexbox Layout Manager** instead of Linear Layout Manager

```
implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
```

Then:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```